# How to override a <tr>'s CSS when loaded by ajax?

Tags: css

I have here an example where you can click on a row and it inserts a new row right underneath.  The new row consists of a new table.

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/33b3M/6/)

As you can see from the fiddle above, there is a hover over CSS in place for each table separately.  The problem is now that the hover over from the parent table covers the second table.

[image]

I rather would like to override the hover over effect from the parent table when hovering over the new row, so that I can see the hover effect of the sub table instead:

[image]

I tried to prevent parent's table CSS to be applied on the new row like this:

```
table.cb_table-hover tbody tr:hover td:not(.override),
table.cb_table-hover tbody tr:hover th:not(.override){
      background-color: #cfe2e8;  
}
```

As you can see in this [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/33b3M/7/):

However the results are not as I expected. What could I be missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this.](http://jsfiddle.net/33b3M/11/)

### CSS

```
table.cb_table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td:not(.override),
table.cb_table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > th:not(.override){
  background-color: #cfe2e8;  
}
```

let me know if this helps you.

I have just added `>` to target direct child

Comment: If you uncomment the sub_table hover script, this works great. http://jsfiddle.net/33b3M/18/

Comment: Thats perfect thank you. However you also had uncommented the sub table's css. This fiddle is now correct: http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/33b3M/16/

Answer (score 0):

Just use the CSS specificity:

```
.cb_inline_block {
    display:inline-block;
}



.cb_table-hover tr:hover td,
.cb_table-hover tr:hover th{
      background-color: #cfe2e8;  
}


.cb_table-hover .sub_table-hover tr:hover td,
.cb_table-hover .sub_table-hover tr:hover th{
      background-color: #cfe2e8;  
}
```